# Fade Out child div images & Fade In an overlapping parent div image using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I’ve created a jsfiddle of my attempt to solve this question here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/oca3L32h/

I have 3 divs that are contained inside a master div. These three divs each contain an image, and they overlap each other. I have 3 radio buttons which decide which div is visible to the viewer (each radio button hides 2 of the divs and makes the remaining div visible).

I’m trying to make a Javascript function that will use AJAX to query my database whenever my page loads, if the Javascript receives “0” as the response, then I want a particular image to appear at 50% opacity over all 3 divs (so that if the viewer clicks on the radio buttons, they’ll still see the 3 different images but there will be another, semi-transparent image appearing over the top of them (this semi-transparent image will also prevent the viewer from interacting with the original image underneath).

For testing purposes I’ve created a “Click me” button that will trigger the Javascript function (as I can’t perform the database check in a jsfiddle), but I’m not able to get the desired result.

This is my Javascript function:

```
//function to show transparent image
function ShowTransparentImage(){

//fade out firstDIV, secondDIV and thirdDIV by 50%
document.getElementById("firstDIV").setAttribute("style","opacity:0.5; -moz-opacity:0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=50)");
document.getElementById("secondDIV").setAttribute("style","opacity:0.5; -moz-opacity:0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=50)");
document.getElementById("thirdDIV").setAttribute("style","opacity:0.5; -moz-opacity:0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=50)");

//fade in masterDiv's image with 50% opacity
document.getElementById("masterDIV.background-image").setAttribute("style","opacity:0.5; -moz-opacity:0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=50)");

};
```

I’m unsure what the rules are for hiding/showing an image that’s overlapping other one. I’m trying to do this by changing the CSS of all 4 divs from inside the Javascript function, but I haven’t been successful.

If it’s not possible to reduce the opacity of the 3 divs to 50%, while increasing the opacity of the master div’s image to 50%, then would it be possible to make the images in the 3 divs invisible (or 100% transparent) while making the master div’s image visible?

Any help or advice with this would be really appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Here's an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flowstoneknight/ky78n858/1/) with fading effects added.

---

From what I understand, you're looking to show one of three images, controlled by the user through radio buttons. Then there is also a semi-transparent image to be displayed overlapping the other images, controlled by some additional JavaScript.

Here is a different approach to achieve that. Instead of changing a bunch of styles through JS each time, it's often better to add/remove a class to elements, and just have a few more rules in your CSS.

Here is a [jsFddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ky78n858/), and the code pasted below just in case.

HTML:

```
<div><input class="transparentImageToggleButton" type="button" value="Toggle Transparent Image" /></div>
<div><input class="radio" type="radio" name="thing" value="0" checked />Image 0</div>
<div><input class="radio" type="radio" name="thing" value="1" />Image 1</div>
<div><input class="radio" type="radio" name="thing" value="2" />Image 2</div>

<div class="masterDiv">
    <div class="imageDiv active">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/400/sports" />
    </div>
    <div class="imageDiv">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/400/food" />
    </div>
    <div class="imageDiv">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/400/nature" />
    </div>
    <img class="masterImage" src="http://placehold.it/400x400?text=master+image" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.masterDiv {
    position: relative;
}

.imageDiv {
    display: none;
}

.imageDiv.active {
    display: block;
}

.masterImage {
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.masterImage.active {
    display: inline;
}
```

JS (with jQuery):

```
$('.transparentImageToggleButton').on('click', function() {
    $('.masterImage').toggleClass('active');
});

$('.radio').on('click', function() {
    $('.imageDiv').removeClass('active').eq($(this).val()).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Hi @flowstoneknight thanks for your reply! It's exactly what I was looking for, I was wondering, is it possible to apply a fade in effect that works across all browsers to the transparent image when it's activated?

Comment: @Emily added some CSS transitions for fading effects. Please see the update at the top of the answer. The `max-width` stuff is to replace `display`, to make transitions work, but still cover/uncover the overlapping images.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `.background-image` from  `document.getElementById("masterDIV.background-image")` , using `.click() to call`ShowTransparentImage`

```
$('.radio input').on('click', function(){
    //Hide all image divs
    $imageDivs.css({'display':'none', opacity:1});
    $("#masterDIV").css({zIndex:0})
    //Then display the image div we want to see
    //To find that out we'll get the id of the current radio button
    var radioID = $(this).attr('id');

    //And then we'll display that image div
    $('#' + radioID + 'DIV').css('display','block'); 
});

//function to show transparent image
$("button").click(function ShowTransparentImage(){

  //fade out firstDIV, secondDIV and thirdDIV by 50%
  document.getElementById("firstDIV")
  .setAttribute("style","opacity:0.5; -moz-opacity:0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=50)");
  document.getElementById("secondDIV")
  .setAttribute("style","opacity:0.5; -moz-opacity:0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=50)");
  document.getElementById("thirdDIV")
  .setAttribute("style","opacity:0.5; -moz-opacity:0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=50)");

  //fade in masterDiv's image with 50% opacity
  document.getElementById("masterDIV")
  .setAttribute("style","opacity:0.5; -moz-opacity:0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=50);z-index:2");   
});
```

css

```
#masterDIV{
    opacity:0;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
     position: absolute;
    background-image: url(https://jonathanhult.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/padlock.png);
}
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/oca3L32h/5/

Comment: Hi @guest271314 thanks for your reply. I've tried your suggestion but unfortunately it's reducing the opacity of the master div (and everything in it, including the 3 other divs) to 50%. I need the master div's image (https://jonathanhult.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/padlock.png) to fade in and sit on top of the images in the 3 other divs instead. That's why I was trying to target the master div's image instead of targeting the master div as a whole.

Comment: Not possible to set opacity of parent element to 0.5 and simultaneously have child element opacity greater than 0.5 . Could adjust html to remove #masterDIV as parent element of #firstDIV , #secondDIV, #thirdDiv ; move #masterDIV to position over three div elements . See updated post , http://jsfiddle.net/oca3L32h/4/

Comment: Hi @guest271314 thanks for your reply, it's closer to what I'm looking for, but the effect disappears when the radio buttons are clicked on, the other answer is closer to what I need, but thanks again for your answer.

Comment: Is requirement for effect to remain once set ?

Comment: Hi, yes I need it to stay applied even if the user clicks through the radio buttons.